# Heartbleed POC: Is this sensitive information?

Tags: tls, penetration-test, exploit, openssl, heartbleed

In order to demonstrate the Heartbleed problem, I executed a publicly available exploit against a vulnerable old NAS web-server that has since been replaced.

Below is an excerpt from the subsequent output: 
(Some of which, appears to be binary or encrypted.)

```
...................................................................../index.php......RC4-SHA.RC4-SHA.Xq?...............?.......?.....index...php.ex.h....................SHA.application
/x-httpd-php.mod_ssl/2.2.14..mod_ssl/2.2.14..OpenSSL/1.0.1e..OpenSSL/1.0.1e..TLSv1.2.NULL....RC4-SHA.RC4-SHA.false...false.............128...128...............128...128.....NONE....3.......3........
ABF42CCAC60E1D07........ABF42CCAC60E1D07........ABF42CCAC60E1D07........Jul 12 04:20:13 2011 /L=Taipei/O=QNAP Systems Inc./OU=NAS/CN=TS Series NAS/emailAddress=q_support@qnap.com....
/C=TW/ST=Taiwan/L=Taipei/O=QNAP Systems Inc./OU=NAS/CN=TS Series NAS...q_support@qnap.com......q_support@qnap.com......
/C=TW/ST=Taiwan/L=Taipei/O=QNAP Systems Inc./OU=NAS/CN=TS Series NAS/emailAddress=q_support@qnap.com..../C=TW/ST=Taiwan/L=Taipei/O=QNAP Systems Inc./OU=NAS/CN=TS Series 
NAS/emailAddress=q_support@qnap.com....TW......TW......Taiwan..Taiwan..Taipei..Taipei..\T.BdT.BPTTH,N.B..?._LSSDN.B8.?._LSSXN.BH.?._LSShN.BP.?._LSS|N.B`.?._LSS.N.Bp.?._LSS.N.B..?._LSS.N.B..?._ 
LSS.N.B..?._LSS.Q.B..?._LSS.Q.B..?._LSS.Q.BH.?._LSS.Q.B..?._LSS.Q.B0.?._LSS.R.B..?._LSS.R.B..?._LSS,R.B..?._LSS@R.B..?._LSSTR.B..?._LSShR.B..?._LSS.R.B@.?._LSS.S.B..?._LSS.S.B0.?._LSS0S.B@.?._
LSSDS.BP.?._LSSXS.B..?._LSSlS.B..?._LSS.S.B..?._LSS.T.B(.?._LSS$T.BP.?._LSS8T.Bx.?._LSSLT.B..?._LSS.............................................................................................
.............................................................................................................QNAP Systems Inc........QNAP Systems Inc........NAS.....NAS.....TS Series NAS...TS Series
NAS...q_support@qnap.com......q_support@qnap.com......rsaEncryption...rsaEncryption...sha1WithRSAEncryption...sha1WithRSAEncryption...F12392A6F7C71C1A30642791B394C4BBAF8103A6772BD28E387CBD4979FC7AEE
........F12392A6F7C71C1A30642791B394C4BBAF8103A6772BD28E387CBD4979FC7AEE..............................................................................................................................
```

What exactly is this data?

In particular; these hexadecimal character strings look like some sort of keys/hashes:

```
F12392A6F7C71C1A30642791B394C4BBAF8103A6772BD28E387CBD4979FC7AEE
```

```
ABF42CCAC60E1D07
```

Is this information of any particular use or interest to would-be attackers / eaves-droppers??

Comment: This seems to be a part of a certificate. If I am right and this it is a certificate, then it is not sensitive.

Comment: The bit that "remains encrypted" could easily be the private key.

Comment: @Polynomial Implying that the server wasn't vulnerable? Or that the exploit failed?

Comment: @tjt263 The exploit definitely worked. You just need to do memory forensics to extract interesting info from the blob that came back.

Answer (score 4):

Heartbleed results in arbitrary server memory being disclosed. Sometimes this contains sensitive information. In some cases, this is the server's private key, which can be the most sensitive information on the server. In many cases, it can contain information that is intended for a different client. This is probably what you are seeing: certificates, version strings, and other information used internally by the web server.

Comment: Hey, @bonsaiviking. ***"Heartbleed results in arbitrary server memory being disclosed."*** So it comes directly from the RAM of the vulnerable host? Am I reading that right?

Comment: @tjt263 Yes, that's right.

Comment: So, that's kind of incredible. And the encrypted-looking content is probably actually, like.. raw binary data, then?

Comment: @tjt263 could be possibly anything from junk to cyptographic keys

Comment: @Lukas Wouldn't it be "human-readable" if that were the case?

Answer (score 2):

Heartbleed exposes, as the other answer mentioned, arbitrary memory. On an unused NAS, this is most likely not sensitive information.

Yet, this seems to be a certificate - maybe also, as polynomial said, (part of) the private key.

Executing the exploit several times will probably yield different outputs; putting the pieces together can in fact yield passwords in plain text, tokens and other sensitive information, especially on servers with some usage on them.

Your questions in the comments suggest you didn't understand what the exploit does, though, because nothing "remains encrypted" - you basically get a dump of some portion of memory. If that is actually encrypted memory, heartbleed will not help there.

But more often than not, that "encrypted" (e.g. Random-looking bytes) data may be private keys or internally used symmetric keys.

Try executing the exploit several times in a row with some load on the machine and you will be able to extract the private key for the certificate if you didn't already.

With that, you could do a MITM - yet this is not as interesting for a NAS as is for a publicly reachable web server for example.

Comment: Running the exploit consecutively, in this case, consistantly returns one of two variants of what look like the `top` and `tail` of the same string.

Comment: Right. So stitch it together and you have a private key and a certificate, hopefully.

Comment: I can give you more details, privately, if you want to test it yourself.

Comment: I don't need to, thanks. Did my heartbleed homework when it was due;)

Comment: lol. No worries. This is just independant research for my own interest, though; FYI.